# Incorrect r2 score computed by sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, goodness-of-fit

There is a significant mismatch between r2 score computed by sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score and sklearn.metrics.r2_score. The one computed by permutation_test_score seems to be incorrect; See below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import permutation_test_score

x=np.arange(1,6,1)
x=np.reshape(x,(5,1))
y=np.array([1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6])
y=np.reshape(y,(5,1))

# fit a line to the data
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(x, y)
print lin_reg.intercept_,lin_reg.coef_
# 1.97 -0.11

# Compute the prediction values (f) from our fitted line
f=lin_reg.predict(x)
print f
# [[ 1.86]
#  [ 3.83]
#  [ 5.8 ]
#  [ 7.77]
#  [ 9.74]]

# Calculate R^2 explicitly
yminusf2=(y-f)**2
sserr=sum(yminusf2)
mean=float(sum(y))/float(len(y))
yminusmean2=(y-mean)**2
sstot=sum(yminusmean2)
R2=1.-(sserr/sstot)
print R2
# 0.99766067

# Use sklearn.metrics.r2_score
print r2_score(y,f)
# 0.99766066838
print r2_score(y,f) == R2
# [ True]

# Use sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score
r2_sc, perm_sc, pval = permutation_test_score(lin_reg,x,y, n_permutations = 100, scoring = 'r2', cv =None)
print r2_sc
# 0.621593653548
print r2_sc ==R2
# [False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it differs. You are getting the score on whole data (i.e fitting on `x` and also predicting on same). So `R2` and r2_score() are very high. But as for your question, it differs because the `permutation_test_score()` doesnt calculate score on whole data, but uses a cross-validation technique and outputs the average of scores got over all folds.

Notice that the `permutation_test_score()` also has a parameter `cv`, which if not specified or None, defaults to a 3-fold cross-validation (equal to KFold(3)) as [specified in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score.html):

> cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
>
> ```
> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs for cv are:
>        - None, to use the default 3-fold cross validation,
>        - integer, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold,
>        - An object to be used as a cross-validation generator.
>        - An iterable yielding train, test splits.
> ```

So, the score returned by the permutation_test_score is the average of all scores obtained by the cross-validation.

You can test this scenario by using [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score) which returns the score for each fold:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
r2_sc_cv = cross_val_score(lin_reg,x,y, scoring = 'r2', cv =None)
print r2_sc_cv
# array([ 0.91975309,  0.94502787,  0.        ])

r2_sc_cv_mean = np.average(r2_sc_cv)
print r2_sc_cv_mean
# 0.62159365354781015

print r2_sc_cv_mean == r2_sc
# True
```

See the score in last fold of the `r2_sc_cv` array. Its 0.0. That is why the average score is coming down for you.